# read file names from directory w/ python

Tags: python, filenames, pygame, py2exe, distutils

I'm trying to make a pygame executable.  I will use the following setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup( 
  console = [ "game.py" ],
  author = "me",
  data_files = [ ( directory, [ file_1, file_2... ] ) ]
)
```

I've gotten this to work fine on a simple game, but the game I want to package up has > 700 image files.  My question is, is there a simple way to read all file names from a directory so I don't have to list each one separately?

While there are some files that are numbered in sequence, most have a different root name, so writing a loop that makes the appropriate strings is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Here , `data_files = [ ( directory, [ file_1, file_2... ] )`, a `[` seems to be extra. Please correct it.

Comment: for anyone else with this problem, [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) also helped me understand what the setup script does with data_files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import os

data_files = [(x[0], x[2]) for x in os.walk(root_dir)]
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

This will give you the files for every subdirectory contained within `root_dir` (along with the ones in `root_dir` itself, of course) as tuples in the format `[(dirpath1, [file1, file2, ...]), (dirpath2, [file3, file4, ...]), ...]`

I gave you this as my answer because I'm assuming (or rather, hoping) that, with so many files, you're keeping them properly organized rather than having them all in a single directory with no subdirectories.

---

It's been a while, but coming back to this I now realize that for a long list of files, a generator expression would probably be more efficient. To do so, a very simple change is needed; replace the outer brackets with parentheses, i.e.

```
import os
data_file_gen = ((x[0], x[2]) for x in os.walk(root_dir))
```

And `data_file_gen` could then be used wherever `data_files` was iterated over (assuming you're only using the generator once; if the generator is to be used multiple times, you would have to recreate the generator for each use. In such cases it may be better to just use the list method unless memory does become a problem.).

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 6):

The `os` module has a method called `listdir` that takes a path and returns the contents as a list.

Comment: Note that the list is not sorted. That can be done with the `sorted` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
data_files = [directory, ...]  # whatever you want to put specifically.
data_files += [file for file in os.listdir('images') if os.path.isfile(file)]  # for adding your image files
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to include the directory listed in os.path.isfile, assuming it isn't the cwd.

    `dir = 'images'`
    `data_files += [file for file in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(dir + file)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use glob to collect all files in a directory. Use *.* to collect all files, or *.jpg to collect all .jpg files. This will put the images in a folder called "Images" in your py2exe output directory.

```
...
from glob import glob
...
data_files = [
        ("Stuff", glob(r'C:\projectfolder\Stuff\*.*')) 
        ,("dlls", glob(r'C:\projectfolder\dlls\*.dll'))                  
        ,("Images", glob(r'C:\projectfolder\images\*.*'))  
         ]  
...
setup(
name='ProjectName'
,options = options
,data_files=data_files
,console=['projectname.py']
)
```